# Oracle SQL Developer -- IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to play with some PL/SQL functions so I installed Oracle SQL Developer using [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04) instructions. Now I want to create a test database, add some tables/views and start testing queries. I followed [these](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm?cid=4205&ssid=115580667286425) instructions and I get `IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection`. I googled a lot, but all I found out is that:

1. Some sort of Oracle service (listener?) has to be running
2. I have to install a loopback device if I want a local DB

`start lsnrctl` tells me that there is no such task as lsnrctl.

When I run `ifconfig` it says that I actually have `lo` interface... and I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle client?

Comment: @Donal no, why should I?

Comment: Not really, it depends on the driver you have configured. It may be easier if you have the Oracle Client. See here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/01/oracle-sql-developer-4-and-the-oracle-client/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you right. You have to startup database and the listener. Listener normally works on TCP port 1521. So try telnet on it. Nice tool to check whether oracle db works is 'tnsping'. So you can try tnsping localhost.

Comment: You have to install OracleDatabase. It is part of oracle client or oracle database.